# Multicolor heading should change in one color on hover using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have two title combined, which has their own CSS and want to change it in one color on hover at same time. So as text1 is in black color and text2 is in gray color but on hover both text should change in blue color at same time not one by one. Please suggest any idea. Thanks in advance.

```css
.text1{color: black}
.text2{color: gray}

/* Below code is not required */
.container > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: Transparent;
}
.container > a > div:hover{color:blue;}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <a href='#'>
    <div class='text1'>
      Hello
    </div>
    <div class='text2'>
      World!
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the selecor so that you're targeting `:hover` on the `container` and using child selectors to change all the child divs' color:

```css
.text1{color: black}
.text2{color: gray}

.container > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: Transparent;
}
.container:hover > a > div {
    color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <a href='#'>
  <div class='text1'>
  Hello
  </div>
  <div class='text2'>
  World!
  </div>
  </a>
</div>
```